# Notepad++ MarkdownViewer++ Change URL color

Tags: notepad++

I am using Obsidian theme in Notepad++ using MarkdownViewer++. The color to URL links appear dark purple - making it very difficult to see. Any suggestion what I do to update to change the URL link color? This is how it appears -

[image]